# 50 pushups as soon as waking up

Tags: exercise

When I wake up, I feel a surge of energy, so why waste it. I do a set of 50 pushups to start the day, and I feel great.

But my question is this: I am sure that this is good for my body, but how will this affect my energy level as the morning goes on during a demanding workday?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel exhausted after doing them, it should have no negative effect at all.

I wouldn't think that the exercise you do in the morning will effect a long work day at all.

If you feel it in your body after a hard work day it's likely more stress from the day you may be feeling.

Just listen to your body, maybe have a rest every 10 pressups you do.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,
If you always feel that energy just go on. there's nothing to worry about.
Morning pushups had a great effect on my body and specially my chest muscles when i was a kickboxer.
Conculsion: the most important thing always is that you enjoy your workout, worry about lack of motivation and nothing else ;)
Nice day, and nice workout.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, this should increase your energy levels throughout the day.

Unlike energy in physics, energy in fitness is not a zero-sum affair. You can actually get more of it by expending it. Maybe think of it as an investment.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer. I know that your body is not like a car using up your fuel, but my exertions in the morning will create more fuel? I understand that this is probably a complex question, but generally speaking please?